# Laravel i am not able to link storage on my server (Production)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel for a website, of which slider is dynamic, can be added from admin, to store I’m using laravel storage

When i add slider, the image is uploaded to `laravel/storage/app/public/settings/slider`

When i try the command `php artisan storage:link`, I am getting the following error:

```
ErrorException  : symlink(): No such file or directory

  at /home/invplatform/investors/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:263
    259|      */
    260|     public function link($target, $link)
    261|     {
    262|         if (! windows_os()) {
  > 263|             return symlink($target, $link);
    264|         }
    265|
    266|         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    267|

  Exception trace:

  1   symlink("/home/invplatform/investors/storage/app/public", "/home/invplatform/investors/public/storage")
      /home/invplatform/investors/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:263

  2   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::link("/home/invplatform/investors/storage/app/public", "/home/invplatform/investors/public/storage")
      /home/invplatform/investors/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php:35

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

My `config/filesystem.php` code is

```
    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        ],

    ],
```

I am using blow code for storing image is

```
if($request->has('image'))
        {
            $image_path=request()->image->hashName();
            $request->file('image')->store('/settings/slider');

            $slider->image='settings/slider/'.$image_path;
        }
```

Now when i am adding the image it is uploaded to `laravel/storage/app/public/settings/slider`
but not found in `public_html/storage/settings/slider`

Anyone has any idea about this

Comment: Laravel can't find your directory. As you can see in your description, your file is uploaded to `laravel/...` root directory but, your root directory seems to be `/home/invplatform/investors/`. Maybe you need to check your installation path

Comment: where can i check the installation path

Comment: Please write your full paths bot of them public and storage

Comment: i think need to replace public with public_html right..?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have wrong directory structure. (i think you are using cpanel). So your **public** folder and **storage** folder must be in same directory for `php artisan storage:link`. If these must be in different directory please manually create symlink.

```
ln -s {source-filename} {symbolic-filename}
```

Comment: Im using laravel with homestead, and i get this error locally?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 did you symlink? php artisan storage:link

Comment: Got it working after some time, thanks :)